# Graph coloring as a matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, coloring, algebraic-graph-theory

Is there anything interesting to be gained from representing a graph coloring as a matrix, where the rows correspond to vertices of the graph and columns to colors, and entry i,j = 1 if vertex i is colored with color j and i, j = 0 otherwise? I suppose we could see a graph coloring as a linear transformation from "color vectors" to "vertex vectors"?

Comment: I haven't seen that, I don't know how it could be used, although there is the [hoffman bound](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379521000689), It works with the adjacency matrix.